# Wriggleling Ads on Sci Fi

Tags: support, advertising

I just had this wriggleling ads on HNQ. My bad for not using an ads blocker but may you check your ad provider to not spam those "incredible trick".

[image]

Related: [We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network)

Comment: Yup, all ads on sci-fi site are animated for me. Netflix, Vimeo, and some local. Eww.

Comment: I just don't want to change culture and Vpn just to have an exhaustive list of 'not ok ads'. '

Comment: https://adblockplus.org/ is what I use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this ad.  We are testing and this type of ad should not be live.  We are addressing it right away.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply here and trying to get rid of it ASAP. However, there's got to be a better way of these not showing up in the first place rather than relying on user reports.

Comment: FWIW I’m personally still seeing animated ads on SFF, just now had one for Citroen (Evans Halshaw) and another for Lexus, one for Howdens and one for National Express. There was even one that was a video but I didn’t see who that was for! Some even change ad after a while.